# .htaccess redirect URL of existing folder

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, xampp

The software I am working on uses ugly urls. To make it easier for users to share projects (it is a project administration package) I want to have a redirect. It should redirect `projectadmin.dev/project/1234` to some other URL. 
I can get this to work on ISS using their web.config files, but Apache is giving me headaches.

For demo purposes I have shortend my current .htaccess file, but it still gives the issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*project/([0-9]+)$ RandomOtherPage.php
```

When I access the url `projectadmin.dev/project/123` it gives me an 403 (Forbidden) error. I think this happens because the folder `project` exists in my project. When I change the .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*projects/([0-9]+)$ RandomOtherPage.php
```

And go to `projectadmin.dev/projects/123` it will work as I intended.

My question: How do I ignore the fact the project folder exist but still have the files in it accessable (eg. `projectadmin.dev/projects/image.jpg` should still work) and have a working redirect with the digits?

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file inside the `/project` folder that also contains mod_rewrite directives?

Comment: No nothing is there, just pictures and some other random files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling `MutliViews`. At the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Unless you had a `.htaccess` file located in the `/project` subdirectory, that also contained mod_rewrite directives, then there shouldn't be a problem if the folder exists or not.

Comment: I created the `.htaccess` file in the `/project` subdirectory and removed the RewriteRules from the root `.htaccess` file. This worked, the `Options -MultiViews` did not work for me, even if I included it  in `<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>`.